# Can we have only Finally block with out Try and Catch?

Tags: java

Can we have only Finally block with out adding Try and Catch block?

Comment: No we can not have. It's the syntax of `try...catch...finally` where the `finally` block is optional.

Comment: What would that finally block do anyway?

Comment: Maybe want something like `Object.finalize()`?

Answer (score 2):

No. We can not. It must be:

```
try {}
catch {}
finally {}
```

or

```
try {}
finally {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `try` block defines the region of code to which the subsequent `finally` applies. What you are suggesting would only amount to some thin syntactic sugar where the entire block of code preceding `finally` would be implicitly wrapped in a `try`.

The `catch` block is optional.